# When I tried to run a node js file .I am getting ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

From google search I came to know that it is because XMLHttp not installed(many sites are saying the same reason).I installed that using install xmlhttprequest. I guess it is installed properly .Again the same error is showing .How can I solve that problem.Since I am on my learning period,I don't have much idea about debugging.I have added the code a little and the error pattern obtained while running in terminal.Can somebody give what is happening and what should i do to overcome this error

```
const setEditModal = (isbn) => {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("GET", `http://localhost:3000/book/${isbn}`, false);
    xhttp.send();
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
            at loadBooks (C:\Users\Hp\book-list.js:38:19)
            at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hp\book-list.js:73:1)
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=XMLHttpRequest+is+not+defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you installed it but it seams that you did't import it:)

```
const {XMLHttpRequest} = require("xmlhttprequest");
```

or

```
import {XMLHttpRequest} from 'xmlhttprequest'
```

depending of your version
documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest)

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response .Included const {XMLHttpRequest} = require("xmlhttprequest"); in the code .That error is gone.But now another error message
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: That append because the url returns an html response instead of JSON as you expected. Try to access the url directly with your browser or via postmap to make sure it returns a valid JSON

Comment: Okay.Let me check that way.Thanks